# velocity is creating multiple mirrors

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I'm running

```
DEBUG=1 JASMINE_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG=1 VELOCITY_DEBUG_MIRROR=1 meteor
```

and I'm getting an expected out

```
[[[[[ ~/Projects/uge-spark/gui ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/executorsSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/frameworkSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/masterSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/offersSpec.js
[velocity] PWD /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui
velocity config = {
  "jasmine-client-integration": {
    "regex": "jasmine/client/integration/.+\\.(js|coffee|litcoffee|coffee\\.md)$",
    "name": "jasmine-client-integration",
    "_regexp": {}
  },
  "jasmine-server-unit": {
    "regex": "jasmine/server/unit/.+\\.(js|coffee|litcoffee|coffee\\.md)$",
    "name": "jasmine-server-unit",
    "_regexp": {}
  }
}
[Velocity.FileCopier] Remove file from mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/executorsSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Remove file from mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/frameworkSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Remove file from mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/masterSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Remove file from mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/offersSpec.js
[velocity] copying fixture /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/velocity_core/default-fixture.js to /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/default-fixture.js.js
[velocity] Mirror: starting at http://localhost:5000/
[velocity] Mirror started { statusCode: 200, url: 'http://localhost:5000/', port: 5000 }
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

then right after that I started getting this error (over and over)

```
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/executorsSpec.js
jasmine-client-integration  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/executorsSpec.js
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/frameworkSpec.js
jasmine-client-integration  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/frameworkSpec.js
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/masterSpec.js
jasmine-client-integration  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/masterSpec.js
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/offersSpec.js
jasmine-client-integration  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/client/integration/offersSpec.js
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
jasmine-server-unit  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
File added: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/packageMocksSpec.js
jasmine-server-unit  <=  /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/packageMocksSpec.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/executorsSpec.js
loading stub file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/frameworkSpec.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/masterSpec.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/packageMocksSpec.js
Started


0 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0 seconds
[Velocity.FileCopier] Replace file in mirror /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/.meteor/local/.mirror/client/jasmine/integration/offersSpec.js
loading stub file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/package-stubs.js
loading source file: /home/juanpa/Projects/uge-spark/gui/tests/jasmine/server/unit/packageMocksSpec.js
Started


0 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.002 second
```

this error makes me think that due to this, my test are not being picked up, any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's creating multiple mirrors, but it does look like your files are not being picked up. Could you please try this with the latest v1.0.0-rc.1 release and post the log?

Comment: Hi Sam,  you already answer me in meteor google group. I'm using the newest version now and this error is fixed for me. Thanks for your support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in v1.0.0-rc.1

Let's make the answer official :)